# Cross validation fails in Spark-ML

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, cross-validation

I have an execution of Spark-ML with a decision tree and a cross validation inside.

It fails for an unknown reason with this stack trace during the cross validation :

> org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
>         org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(CrossValidator.scala:164)
>         org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(CrossValidator.scala:164)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>         scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$4.apply(CrossValidator.scala:164)
>         org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$4.apply(CrossValidator.scala:144)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>         scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.fit(CrossValidator.scala:144)
>         decisionTree.DecisionTreeDisplay.process(DecisionTreeDisplay.scala:151)

Followed by some thread stack traces:

> 2019-01-23 16:26:21 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl:91 - Exception in
>   statusUpdate java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3@764726a7 rejected
>   from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@783b07b9[Shutting down,
>   pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks =
>   4914]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter.enqueueSuccessfulTask(TaskResultGetter.scala:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.liftedTree2$1(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:413)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.statusUpdate(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
>     at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:221)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

My cross validation code is:

```
 // define Cross-Validation
    val cv = new CrossValidator()
      .setEstimator(pipeline)
      .setEvaluator(evaluator)
      .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
      .setNumFolds(3)
      .setSeed(seed)
      .setCollectSubModels(true) // requires version of spark >= 2.3.0
      .setParallelism(8) // requires version of spark >= 2.3.0

    val cvModel = cv.fit(trainInfile) //Fail here
```

In the ML library it seems to fail at line:

```
      val foldMetrics = foldMetricFutures.map(ThreadUtils.awaitResult(_, Duration.Inf))
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does pipeline have custom transformations?. How do you create your trainInfile dataframe?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 yes there is one transformation in the pipeline. The trainInfile is created with the union of 2 dataFrame